# Polynomial convex coefficients

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Assume we have an arbitrary high order polynomial $$f(L)=1-L\theta_1-L^2\theta_2-L^3\theta_3-...-L^N\theta_N$$ and we know all roots of this polynomial site outside the unit circle. It is obvious that the latter condition imposes some restrictions on $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,...$. Then my question is whether this conditions form a convex set.

For example if polynomial is of the order of 1 then

\begin{align*}
 & 1-L\theta =0  \\
& \rightarrow L=1/ \theta  \\
& \rightarrow |1/ \theta|>1 \\
& \rightarrow |\theta|<1
\end{align*}
the last equation forms a convex set. Now is that in general true?

Comment: Can you explain what's an "infinite order polynomial"? I have never heard of such thing.

Comment: Dear @AlexandreEremenko. You mean it is not possible for a polynomial to have a very high order?

Comment: "Very high" or "infinite"?

Comment: There is the Laguerre-Poyla class of functions that are limits of real stable polynomials..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that convexity doesn't hold for all $N$. 
For a polynomial with degree $N$, you may define a new polynomial 
$$ g(L) := L^N f(1/L). $$

We have that $f$ has all of its roots outside the unit circle if and only if $g$ has all of its roots inside the unit circle. This is also known in the literature as $g$ being Schur stable. 
Example 2.3 of [1] shows that the set of Schur stable polynomials for $N=5$ is not convex.

The problem of studying the set of the polynomials which are Schur stable seems to be well known in the literature, see for instance [2] and the references therein. In fact, the person who pointed out Example 2.3 for me was the corresponding author of [2].

[1] Shankar P. Bhattacharyya, H. Chapellat, and Lee H. Keel. **Robust Control: The Parametric Approach.** Upper Saddle River, New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, 1995.

[2]  Baltazar Aguirre-Hernández, José Luis Cisneros-Molina, and Martín-Eduardo Frías-Armenta. **Polynomials in Control Theory Parametrized by Their Roots.** International Journal of Mathematics and Mathematical Sciences (2012).

Comment: Thanks @Shamisen. I think if all the roots of f cite outside a unit circle, then, all the roots of g cite inside and on the border of unit circle. is that true?

Comment: @HAMEDHM a root of f site on the border of the unit circle if and only if a root of g site on the border of the unit circle.

Comment: between, if the answer satisfied you, you may accept this answer by clicking on the green check on the left side :)

Comment: Hello @HAMEDHM, thanks for the vote up! :) 
But I was meaning to accept the question as explained there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Dear @Shamisen, could you please take a look at my question in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168468/compact-and-convex-set

Comment: Dear @HAMEDHM, I took a look but I didn't have any insight... sorry

Comment: Dear @Shamisen. I have the book you mentioned in your reply. It seems my question is to some extend different from the example 2.3. To be precise, I am going to find out whether the stability conditions on coefficients of a polynomial form a convex set. In other word I am concern with the coefficients space in a stable polynomial. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @HAMEDHM, since Jury test (or another equivalent test) gives necessary and sufficient conditions on the coefficients of the polynomial to it be Schur stable, the fact that exists a unstable polynomial along the segment between the polynomials presented in Example 2.3 means that the coefficient space of a Jury stable polynomial isn't always convex.

Comment: In a certain limit, turns out Schur polynomials are also Schur stable... :)